# Finding table/field names in forms

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

I am in the process of making a report in SAP B1.

I am trying to look for the table/field names relative to the information I am using. I'm able to see most of the table/field names using the "View > System information" function.

One issue I am having is, I am unable to see the table/field names on some forms. The data is instead displayed like the following:

[Form=202 Item=2 Pane=0 Column=2 Row=12 Variable= 60]

It's my understanding that these forms are created in Adobe software. I however do not have this software installed so I am unable to open pre-existing forms.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I could find the table/field names within these forms?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the Adobe thing is a red herring. There's software called Screen Painter that you can use to lay out a form, but I don't think this helps with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The SAP Business One client won't show you the field mappings for some form items.

One workaround is to infer the table names based on the naming convention used. You can usually find the table name of the 'head' record by using the System Information function on one of the main form items, like a document number field. So for the Production Order form this will tell you the head record is in the table 'OWOR'.

Typically, child rows of data are held in tables where the initial 'O' of the table name is dropped and a number added, e.g. 'WOR1', 'WOR2', etc.

The server may have the SAP Business One SDK installed. If it has, the SDK has full documentation on database structure.

Answer (score 0):

What version of B1 are you using? Because if it's a newer version you can use the SAP Business One Studio suite to open the forms and see the datasources that are mapped in

> [Form=202 Item=2 Pane=0 Column=2 Row=12 Variable= 60]

In this case variable 60 will indicate what table or field is used. To Use B1 Studio Suite (once it's installed, you can extract the form through either of 2 methods (in both cases the form you want to extract needs to first be open in Business One):

1) Through Visual Studio directly: Start a blank c# project, and Add New Item, SAP Business one System Form, and select the form in question from the list that appears. From here you should be able to trace down the datasource and decipher what the actual table / field is.

2) Through B1: Click Tools -> SAP Business One Studio Suite -> Edit Active Form in Sap Business One Studio for Microsoft Visual Studio. form will then open up for edit in Visual Studio (note: need to already have VS open for this method as you have to tell B1 which devenv.exe process you want to use)

Most times that a table/field name is not displayed it's because it's a calculated field or something like a CFL.

Oh and if SAP Business One Studio Suite isn't available, Screen Painter can be used to open the form (although it's a bit clunkier then B1 Studio) or you can extract the form as XML, and open it in a text editor and match the datasources that way - but the visual aid really helps with the size of these forms.